# IIS reverse proxy and resources not found

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, proxy, grafana

Enviroment:

- On the server I have running application on port 3000 (Grafana)
- On the same server I have IIS an running default site at port 80
- I have more applications running on default site and they are accissible as http://myserver.com/myapp1 etc...

What I want to achieve:

- I want to hide grafana server so it will not be accessible throught http://myserver.com:3000, but as http://myserver.com/grafana

I learned that this can be done with URL rewrite and ARR, but when I followed many articles (for example http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis), it was working only partially. The header was rewrited, but no page resources was found because for example http://myserver.com/grafana/scripts/script.js is not there. I understand, that physically the file is not there, because it is in http://myserver.com:3000/scripts/script.js, but I don't know why the page is loaded correctly, but resources not? Am I missing something or am I doing something wrong?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally found out solution, the main mistake was, that I did not set outbound rules in URL rewrite, I just set inbound rules, so the resources pathts were invalid. Thank to this article http://blog.cellenza.com/archi-patterns-bp/reverse-proxy-iis-url-rewrite/ I managed to set all the things correctly.